# Android button: How to change icon programatically

Tags: android, android-button, material-components-android

I create a list of cards dinamically from XML data by inflating an XML layout. This layout has a button with dummy values to supress the warnings by the IDE, and I want to set the label and the leading icon according to the data from that XML resource.

I can set the label, but I can't find a method to change the `app:icon` property.

**layout.xml:**

```
...
<Button
    android:id="@+id/listItemAction"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/misc_load" <!-- dummy value -->
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_round_help_24" <!-- dummy value --> />
...
```

**Adapter.java:**

```
...
viewHolder.action.setText(list.get(position).label); // it works
viewHolder.action.setIcon(list.get(position).icon); // there is no such method
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your are using a Material Components theme your `Button` is replaced ad runtime with a `MaterialButton`.

To apply the method `setIcon` you have to use a `MaterialButton`:

```
(button as MaterialButton).icon  = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.xxx)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following two methods

```
// Using icon resource ID
textButton.setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_show_black_18dp)
// Using icon Drawable
val showDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_show_black_18dp)
textButton.icon = showDrawable
```

Comment: None of these seems to work. I get `Cannot resolve symbol` error.